# Power series of a quaternionic variable q: what is the behavior on the boundary of convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, quaternions, analytic-continuation

Suppose you have a power series $S(-)$ in a quaternion $q$, and the coefficients in S are complex numbers, and the radius of convergence is $1.$ Then the boundary of the region of convergence is the unit $3-$sphere.

> Question A: I am curious about whether the points of convergence of the series $S(z)$, with $z$ a complex number such that $|z|=1,$ generalize for $S(q)$ into interesting curves, or surfaces, or at least sets, on the unit 3-sphere.
>
> Question B: Similar question for the sets of singular points, IF  analytic continuation even makes sense for quaternions. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some motivation? That is, how did you arrive at this thought? Also, what do you mean by a series $S(-)$? My intuition tells me that you'll want to consider some sort of "path integral" in $SU(2),$ and build your idea there.